# How to split an address string

Tags: c#, string, selenium, split

```
ShipTo/Dept#: 0011125227-
BIENVILLE SURGERY CENTER LLC
SUITE 102
6300 EAST LAKE BLVD
VANCLEAVE, Mississippi 39565
```

I want to split the above text and get only -

```
BIENVILLE SURGERY CENTER LLC
SUITE 102
```

after splitting.

Comment: Use `gettext` to get the address and then use `substring`

Comment: You're going to have a hard time splitting that out unless you can guarantee the format of this string to always include a suite number etc.

Answer (score 0):

In C# right ?
this code should works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
       IList<string> names = "ShipTo/Dept#: 0011125227 - BIENVILLE SURGERY CENTER LLC SUITE 102 6300 EAST LAKE BLVD VANCLEAVE, Mississippi 39565".Split('-').Reverse().ToList<string>();
       Console.WriteLine(names[0]);
    }
}
```

from code above, it should give result :
[Result from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nux2P.png)

Update :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass {
     public static void Main (string[] args) {
     IList<string> names = "ShipTo/Dept#: 0011125227 - BIENVILLE SURGERY CENTER LLC SUITE 1022 asdf 6300 EAST LAKE BLVD VANCLEAVE, Mississippi 39565".Split('-').Reverse().ToList<string>();


     string character = Regex.Match(names[0], @"^[^0-9]*").Value.Trim();
     string number = new string(names[0].SkipWhile(c=>!char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(c=>char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());

     Console.WriteLine(character+" "+number);
     }
}
```

[Update Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUn8U.png)

Comment: But sir, I want only

Comment: BIENVILLE SURGERY CENTER LLC SUITE 102